# How to organize complex jquery application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, organization

So I have a problem with my jquery applications entirely. When the application is small it's cool. But when it is quite large it is such a mess.. Nested functions, ajax calls, selectors, dom manipulations. Seems like it's non-containable at all, especially when it has a complex logic.

The functional approach does not help me out much. And I don't see how to use classes and inheritance here in practice. How to organize the code? I have read a lot of articles about prototypical and pseudo classical inheritance but they just explain how things works, like how you can inherit 'Person' from 'Human' or something like this. How can I actually use it in real life?

Comment: +1 Exactly how I feel right now.  Anything to share since you made this question?

Answer (score 6):

I find two things that really help organize javascript. One use objects for encapsulation ( http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript ), and two, write a library for common tasks. The normal refactoring strategies work for javascript, extract functions, commonize, if you have 4 functions doing nearly the same thing, change them to a single function which can handle all four cases.

Comment: +1 couldn't agree more! I firmly believe you need to organise JS just like any other code in your project. All too frequently developers are guilty of shunning JS code and relegating it to the basement - I use to be one of those!
One thing was changed my opinion on this largely misunderstood language was the presentation from Douglas Crockford title "Javascript: The Good Parts" which can be found here [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook)

Answer (score 3):

When planning a large jQuery application that I'm currently working on, I found [this post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/large-scale-jquery/) by Addy Osmani very useful.

Full disclosure, though: we ended up hanging most of our application backbone off of a YUI3 core. All our "controller" code is written in jQuery, but the frontend data model is YUI3.